# batch script to capture all elements whose child element having CDATA and output to xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

I am looking for a batch script that can copy all parent elements whose child elements having `<![CDATA[`....`]]>`in an xml file and output to a new xml file.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<books xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
    <jndi:bindings>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book1">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                  <urlConfig>
                    <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
                    <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                    <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                  </urlConfig>
                ]]>
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book2">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                abc.com
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book3">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                    <urlConfig>
                      <defaults catID="1989" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
                    <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                    <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                  </urlConfig>
                ]]>
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book4">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                <urlConfig>
                      <defaults catID="1990" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
                    <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                    <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                  </urlConfig>
                ]]>
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book5">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                abc.com
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
    </jndi:bindings>
</books>
```

So the expected output has to capture all the parent elements whose child elements having `<![CDATA[`...`]]>`. In this example the parent elements are `<jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book#">`.

Expected output is: output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<books xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
    <jndi:bindings>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book1">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                  <urlConfig>
                    <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
                    <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                    <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                  </urlConfig>
                ]]>
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book3">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                    <urlConfig>
                      <defaults catID="1989" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
                    <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                    <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                  </urlConfig>
                ]]>
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
        <jndi:binding name="property/category/books/book4">
            <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                <urlConfig>
                      <defaults catID="1990" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
                    <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                    <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                      <address>abc.com</address>
                    </urlKey>
                  </urlConfig>
                ]]>
            </jndi:value>
        </jndi:binding>
    </jndi:bindings>
</books>
```

I treid to use xml processor, xslt to process the xml file but somehow xslt processors are not easy to process xml file if the file contains CDATA sections in it.

Comment: Would you mind to use external command line tool?`xml.exe` would be the easiest way -> http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @npocmaka thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately i have to stick with batch file if i am running on windows platform.

Comment: well...it will be a batch.`xml.exe` is command line tool.It's ugly to process an xml with pure batch.Better consider hybrid bat/jscript or bat/vbscript as they have a native libraries to process xmls.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "infile=file.xml"
set "outfile=file.new"
rem IMPORTANT! Put a [tab] and a [space] behind the colon to the delims.
for /f "tokens=1-3delims=<>:     " %%a in ('findstr /nc:"jndi:binding" /c:"![CDATA[" /c:"/jndi:binding" "%infile%"') do (
    if "%%~b:%%~c"=="jndi:binding" set "start=%%a"
    if "%%~b"=="![CDATA[" set "found=%%a"
    if "%%~b:%%~c"=="/jndi:binding" (
        if defined found call set "line=%%line%%%%start%%,%%ap;"
        set "start="
        set "found="
    )
)
sed -n "%line%" "%infile%">"%outfile%"
type "%outfile%"
```

[sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)